Why I can not install installed api-platform package?
On laravel site I have installed api-platform with success :
hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ composer require api-platform/laravel
./composer.json has been updated
Running composer update api-platform/laravel
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Nothing to modify in lock file
Writing lock file
Installing dependencies from lock file (including require-dev)
Nothing to install, update or remove
Generating optimized autoload files
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

   INFO  Discovering packages.

  barryvdh/laravel-debugbar ................................................................................................................... DONE
  hisorange/browser-detect .................................................................................................................... DONE
  laravel/breeze .............................................................................................................................. DONE
  laravel/octane .............................................................................................................................. DONE
  laravel/pulse ............................................................................................................................... DONE
  laravel/sail ................................................................................................................................ DONE
  laravel/telescope ........................................................................................................................... DONE
  laravel/tinker .............................................................................................................................. DONE
  livewire/livewire ........................................................................................................................... DONE
  livewire/volt ............................................................................................................................... DONE
  mews/purifier ............................................................................................................................... DONE
  nesbot/carbon ............................................................................................................................... DONE
  nunomaduro/collision ........................................................................................................................ DONE
  nunomaduro/termwind ......................................................................................................................... DONE
  omnia-digital/livewire-calendar ............................................................................................................. DONE
  sentry/sentry-laravel ....................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/eloquent-sortable .................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-backup ....................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-collection-macros ............................................................................................................ DONE
  spatie/laravel-data ......................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-feed ......................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-health ....................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-livewire-wizard .............................................................................................................. DONE
  spatie/laravel-permission ................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-signal-aware-command ......................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-tags ......................................................................................................................... DONE
  spatie/laravel-translatable ................................................................................................................. DONE
  spatie/php-structure-discoverer ............................................................................................................. DONE
  vedmant/laravel-feed-reader ................................................................................................................. DONE
  willvincent/feeds ........................................................................................................................... DONE
  wire-elements/modal ......................................................................................................................... DONE

132 packages you are using are looking for funding.
Use the `composer fund` command to find out more!
> @php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force

   INFO  Publishing [laravel-assets] assets.

  Copying directory [vendor/laravel/telescope/public] to [public/vendor/telescope] ............................................................ DONE

No security vulnerability advisories found.

But I got error with install command :
hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ php artisan api-platform:install

   ERROR  There are no commands defined in the "api-platform" namespace.

Checking all artisan commands I do not see any "platform" commands :
hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ php artisan
Laravel Framework 11.26.0

Usage:
  command [options] [arguments]

Options:
  -h, --help            Display help for the given command. When no command is given display help for the list command
  -q, --quiet           Do not output any message
  -V, --version         Display this application version
      --ansi|--no-ansi  Force (or disable --no-ansi) ANSI output
  -n, --no-interaction  Do not ask any interactive question
      --env[=ENV]       The environment the command should run under
  -v|vv|vvv, --verbose  Increase the verbosity of messages: 1 for normal output, 2 for more verbose output and 3 for debug

Available commands:
  about                                 Display basic information about your application
  clear-compiled                        Remove the compiled class file
  completion                            Dump the shell completion script
  db                                    Start a new database CLI session
  docs                                  Access the Laravel documentation
  down                                  Put the application into maintenance / demo mode
  env                                   Display the current framework environment
  help                                  Display help for a command
  inspire                               Display an inspiring quote
  list                                  List commands
  migrate                               Run the database migrations
  optimize                              Cache framework bootstrap, configuration, and metadata to increase performance
  serve                                 Serve the application on the PHP development server
  test                                  Run the application tests
  tinker                                Interact with your application
  up                                    Bring the application out of maintenance mode
 auth
  auth:clear-resets                     Flush expired password reset tokens
 backup
  backup:clean                          Remove all backups older than specified number of days in config.
  backup:list                           Display a list of all backups.
  backup:monitor                        Monitor the health of all backups.
  backup:run                            Run the backup.
 breeze
  breeze:install                        Install the Breeze controllers and resources
 cache
  cache:clear                           Flush the application cache
  cache:forget                          Remove an item from the cache
  cache:prune-stale-tags                Prune stale cache tags from the cache (Redis only)
 channel
  channel:list                          List all registered private broadcast channels
 config
  config:cache                          Create a cache file for faster configuration loading
  config:clear                          Remove the configuration cache file
  config:publish                        Publish configuration files to your application
  config:show                           Display all of the values for a given configuration file or key
 data
  data:cache-structures                 Cache the internal data structures
 db
  db:monitor                            Monitor the number of connections on the specified database
  db:seed                               Seed the database with records
  db:show                               Display information about the given database
  db:table                              Display information about the given database table
  db:wipe                               Drop all tables, views, and types
 debugbar
  debugbar:clear                        Clear the Debugbar Storage
 env
  env:decrypt                           Decrypt an environment file
  env:encrypt                           Encrypt an environment file
 event
  event:cache                           Discover and cache the application's events and listeners
  event:clear                           Clear all cached events and listeners
  event:list                            List the application's events and listeners
 health
  health:check                          Run all health checks
  health:list                           List all health checks
  health:queue-check-heartbeat
  health:schedule-check-heartbeat
 install
  install:api                           Create an API routes file and install Laravel Sanctum or Laravel Passport
  install:broadcasting                  Create a broadcasting channel routes file
 key
  key:generate                          Set the application key
 lang
  lang:publish                          Publish all language files that are available for customization
 livewire
  livewire:attribute                    Create a new Livewire attribute class
  livewire:configure-s3-upload-cleanup  Configure temporary file upload s3 directory to automatically cleanup files older than 24hrs
  livewire:copy                         Copy a Livewire component
  livewire:delete                       Delete a Livewire component
  livewire:form                         Create a new Livewire form class
  livewire:layout                       Create a new app layout file
  livewire:make                         Create a new Livewire component
  livewire:move                         Move a Livewire component
  livewire:publish                      Publish Livewire configuration
  livewire:stubs                        Publish Livewire stubs
  livewire:upgrade                      Interactive upgrade helper to migrate from v2 to v3
 make
  make:cache-table                      [cache:table] Create a migration for the cache database table
  make:cast                             Create a new custom Eloquent cast class
  make:channel                          Create a new channel class
  make:class                            Create a new class
  make:command                          Create a new Artisan command
  make:component                        Create a new view component class
  make:controller                       Create a new controller class
  make:data                             Create a new data class
  make:enum                             Create a new enum
  make:event                            Create a new event class
  make:exception                        Create a new custom exception class
  make:factory                          Create a new model factory
  make:interface                        Create a new interface
  make:job                              Create a new job class
  make:job-middleware                   Create a new job middleware class
  make:listener                         Create a new event listener class
  make:livewire                         Create a new Livewire component
  make:mail                             Create a new email class
  make:middleware                       Create a new HTTP middleware class
  make:migration                        Create a new migration file
  make:model                            Create a new Eloquent model class
  make:notification                     Create a new notification class
  make:notifications-table              [notifications:table] Create a migration for the notifications table
  make:observer                         Create a new observer class
  make:policy                           Create a new policy class
  make:provider                         Create a new service provider class
  make:queue-batches-table              [queue:batches-table] Create a migration for the batches database table
  make:queue-failed-table               [queue:failed-table] Create a migration for the failed queue jobs database table
  make:queue-table                      [queue:table] Create a migration for the queue jobs database table
  make:request                          Create a new form request class
  make:resource                         Create a new resource
  make:rule                             Create a new validation rule
  make:scope                            Create a new scope class
  make:seeder                           Create a new seeder class
  make:session-table                    [session:table] Create a migration for the session database table
  make:test                             Create a new test class
  make:trait                            Create a new trait
  make:view                             Create a new view
  make:volt                             Create a new Volt component
 migrate
  migrate:fresh                         Drop all tables and re-run all migrations
  migrate:install                       Create the migration repository
  migrate:refresh                       Reset and re-run all migrations
  migrate:reset                         Rollback all database migrations
  migrate:rollback                      Rollback the last database migration
  migrate:status                        Show the status of each migration
 model
  model:prune                           Prune models that are no longer needed
  model:show                            Show information about an Eloquent model
 octane
  octane:install                        Install the Octane components and resources
  octane:reload                         Reload the Octane workers
  octane:start                          Start the Octane server
  octane:status                         Get the current status of the Octane server
  octane:stop                           Stop the Octane server
 optimize
  optimize:clear                        Remove the cached bootstrap files
 package
  package:discover                      Rebuild the cached package manifest
 permission
  permission:cache-reset                Reset the permission cache
  permission:create-permission          Create a permission
  permission:create-role                Create a role
  permission:setup-teams                Setup the teams feature by generating the associated migration.
  permission:show                       Show a table of roles and permissions per guard
 pulse
  pulse:check                           Take a snapshot of the current server's pulse
  pulse:clear                           [pulse:purge] Delete all Pulse data from storage
  pulse:restart                         Restart any running "work" and "check" commands
  pulse:work                            Process incoming Pulse data from the ingest stream
 queue
  queue:clear                           Delete all of the jobs from the specified queue
  queue:failed                          List all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:flush                           Flush all of the failed queue jobs
  queue:forget                          Delete a failed queue job
  queue:listen                          Listen to a given queue
  queue:monitor                         Monitor the size of the specified queues
  queue:prune-batches                   Prune stale entries from the batches database
  queue:prune-failed                    Prune stale entries from the failed jobs table
  queue:restart                         Restart queue worker daemons after their current job
  queue:retry                           Retry a failed queue job
  queue:retry-batch                     Retry the failed jobs for a batch
  queue:work                            Start processing jobs on the queue as a daemon
 route
  route:cache                           Create a route cache file for faster route registration
  route:clear                           Remove the route cache file
  route:list                            List all registered routes
 sail
  sail:add                              Add a service to an existing Sail installation
  sail:install                          Install Laravel Sail's default Docker Compose file
  sail:publish                          Publish the Laravel Sail Docker files
 schedule
  schedule:clear-cache                  Delete the cached mutex files created by scheduler
  schedule:interrupt                    Interrupt the current schedule run
  schedule:list                         List all scheduled tasks
  schedule:run                          Run the scheduled commands
  schedule:test                         Run a scheduled command
  schedule:work                         Start the schedule worker
 schema
  schema:dump                           Dump the given database schema
 sentry
  sentry:publish                        Publishes and configures the Sentry config.
  sentry:test                           Generate a test event and send it to Sentry
 storage
  storage:link                          Create the symbolic links configured for the application
  storage:unlink                        Delete existing symbolic links configured for the application
 structure-scouts
  structure-scouts:cache                Cache discoverers within your application
  structure-scouts:clear                Clear cached discoverers within your application
 stub
  stub:publish                          Publish all stubs that are available for customization
 telescope
  telescope:clear                       Delete all Telescope data from storage
  telescope:install                     Install all of the Telescope resources
  telescope:pause                       Pause all Telescope watchers
  telescope:prune                       Prune stale entries from the Telescope database
  telescope:publish                     Publish all of the Telescope resources
  telescope:resume                      Unpause all Telescope watchers
 vendor
  vendor:publish                        Publish any publishable assets from vendor packages
 view
  view:cache                            Compile all of the application's Blade templates
  view:clear                            Clear all compiled view files
 volt
  volt:install                          Install all of the Volt resources

In composer.json :
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "type": "project",
    "description": "The skeleton application for the Laravel framework.",
    "keywords": [
        "laravel",
        "framework"
    ],
    "license": "MIT",
    "require": {
        "php": "^8.2",
        "api-platform/laravel": "*",
        "bugsnag/bugsnag-laravel": "^2.0",
        "danharrin/livewire-rate-limiting": "^1.3",
        "hisorange/browser-detect": "^5.0",
        "intervention/image": "^3.7",
        "laravel/breeze": "^2.1",
        "laravel/framework": "^11.9",
        "laravel/octane": "^2.5",
        "laravel/pulse": "^1.2",
        "laravel/telescope": "^5.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.9",
        "livewire/livewire": "^3.5",
        "livewire/volt": "^1.6",
        "mews/purifier": "^3.4",
        "omnia-digital/livewire-calendar": "^3.1",
        "predis/predis": "^2.2",
        "sentry/sentry-laravel": "^4.7",
        "spatie/cpu-load-health-check": "^1.0",
        "spatie/laravel-backup": "^8.8",
        "spatie/laravel-data": "^4.7",
        "spatie/laravel-feed": "^4.4",
        "spatie/laravel-health": "^1.29",
        "spatie/laravel-livewire-wizard": "^2.3",
        "spatie/laravel-permission": "^6.7",
        "spatie/laravel-sluggable": "^3.6",
        "spatie/laravel-tags": "^4.6",
        "spatie/security-advisories-health-check": "^1.2",
        "vedmant/laravel-feed-reader": "^1.6",
        "willvincent/feeds": "^2.6",
        "wire-elements/modal": "^2.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-debugbar": "^3.13",
        "fakerphp/faker": "^1.23",
        "laravel/pint": "^1.13",
        "laravel/sail": "^1.26",
        "mockery/mockery": "^1.6",
        "nunomaduro/collision": "^8.0",
        "phpstan/phpstan": "^1.12",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^11.0.1"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "app/Library/helper.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app/",
            "Database\\Factories\\": "database/factories/",
            "Database\\Seeders\\": "database/seeders/"
        }
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "post-autoload-dump": [
            "Illuminate\\Foundation\\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump",
            "@php artisan package:discover --ansi"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-assets --ansi --force"
        ],
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "@php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        "post-create-project-cmd": [
            "@php artisan key:generate --ansi",
            "@php -r \"file_exists('database/database.sqlite') || touch('database/database.sqlite');\"",
            "@php artisan migrate --graceful --ansi"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "laravel": {
            "dont-discover": []
        }
    },
    "config": {
        "optimize-autoloader": true,
        "preferred-install": "dist",
        "sort-packages": true,
        "allow-plugins": {
            "pestphp/pest-plugin": true,
            "php-http/discovery": true
        }
    },
    "minimum-stability": "stable",
    "prefer-stable": true
}


hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ php -v
PHP 8.2.21 (cli) (built: Jul  4 2024 16:26:28) (NTS)
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v4.2.21, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v8.2.21, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v3.3.2, Copyright (c) 2002-2024, by Derick Rethans

hoster@hoster-os:/Project$ uname  -a
Linux hoster-os 6.5.0-35-generic #35~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue May  7 09:00:52 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Reading manuals
Thanks in advance!

Run php artisan vendor:publish --tag=api-platform?

I got : ` php artisan vendor:publish --tag=api-platform
INFO  No publishable resources for tag [api-platform].  `

have you done, composer install/ composer update?
